# Can SignalR connection IDs be faked?

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

Just how is the connection ID determined in SignalR? Could a user purposefully use another person's connection ID to pretend to be them?

Obviously there's the difficulty of determining another person's connection ID since there's so many possible IDs. However, my application would make users aware of other user's connection IDs because the application requires peers to interact and I've used the connection ID as a unique user ID.

Can the connection IDs be chosen by users? And can users somehow switch to another, known ID or is there some other protection in place?

I refer to the connection IDs that are obtained server side via `Context.ConnectionId`.

Comment: A client cannot choose or set their connection ID. It is set by the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The connection id is assigned by the server. However apart from the connection id the server also sends a connection token which is calculated using a few pieces of information including the connection id. If the server receives a request where connection id and connection token don't match the request will be rejected. If you want to understand how the SignalR protocol works in general read a [post](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/) I wrote some time ago . If you want more details on connection id and connection token read [this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/introduction-to-security#connectiontoken).